# GWT RequestFactory and Server Push?

Tags: gwt, comet, spring-roo, requestfactory, errai

1- I have already used the following frameworks (Event based client-server) on GWT projects, and works fine with RPC call architecture.

- [GWT-Comet](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/)
- [GwtEventService](https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/)

After searching, i found a lot of frameworks that treat the client server messaging exchange problem:

**2- [Jboss Errai framework](http://errai.github.io/)**

Great messaging service but i've not used it. I searched for only errai bus usage with gwt but nothing founded.

**3- [Atmosphere Framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)**

Seem to do same thing like comet but i've not used it.
http://async-io.org/tutorial.html

**4- [WebSocket](http://www.websocket.org/)**

**5- [Spring-Integration-Cometd](http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-java/server/services/integration-spring)**

**6- [Spring WebSocket](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/24/spring-framework-4-0-m2-websocket-messaging-architectures/)**

NOW :

I want to develop a project with Spring roo and GWT.
As Spring roo gwt based on RequestFactory architecture.

I think that we can use Comet or gwteventservice with RequestFactory architecture, but we need [AutoBean](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) to generate client side Entity interface on server side.

**My question concern GWT RequestFactory :**

How to integrate one of the frameworks above in gwt projects based on RequestFactory architecture? Is there any example ?!

Thanks